# What is a word for 'being discrepant from something'?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm writing a report and I want to describe some data points A becomes discrepant from data points B when a control parameter increases. I think I have learned a one-word expression for *being discrepant from something*, but I can't remember it. I think it was like *divert* or something, but the dictionary says *divert* has another meaning, not what I intended. Could anyone recommend such a word?

---

**Update**

I've attached an example figure. [image]

What I want to describe is that the graph is gradually changing from the solid line to the dotted line, as in the figure.

Comment: Do you maybe mean they *[diverge](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Dictionary+diverge)*, or are *divergent*?

Comment: @Jan I'd expect that's the correct word as well. It certainly fits the mathematical definition.